Native react pn android studio
I have been trying to launch my first react application, and I keep getting this error:
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\PHEMELO MOLOI\AwesomeProject\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-7c8733e9-b362-489d-a434-ac2dfad98cc4) to immutable location (C:\Users\PHEMELO MOLOI\AwesomeProject\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a) > Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\PHEMELO MOLOI\AwesomeProject\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-7c8733e9-b362-489d-a434-ac2dfad98cc4) to immutable location (C:\Users\PHEMELO MOLOI\AwesomeProject\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a) * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 4s

I tried reinstalling all of the dependencies, I ran react-native doctor and got this:
Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 34.0.0

Errors:   1

I tried using a lower version sdk because the guide said higher ones might fail, but even the latest ones fail. When I run the fix option it installs the commandline tools then says it needs a restart. Afterwards it still gives me the same error.
